# How should I correctly use “sollen”?

Tags: word-usage, difference, subjunctive

What do these two sentences mean?

> Ich soll das Buch lesen.
>
> Ich sollte das Buch lesen.

I have mostly seen *should* translated as *sollte*, but that seems to be past tense. The first one would be “I should read the book” and the second one “I should have read the book.”

I believe this is incorrect, however. What is the proper use of this verb? What is the difference between *ich soll*, *ich [solle](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&lang=de&input=sollen&features=(Cat%20V))*, and *ich sollte*?

Comment: Related: [Difference between “Das sollst du nicht” and “Das solltest …”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17300/difference-between-das-sollst-du-nicht-and-das-solltest)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Ich soll das Buch lesen

means "**I'm supposed to read this book**", like when a teacher assigns you the book to read as your homework.

> Ich sollte das Buch lesen.

can mean both "**I should read this book**", as in "all things considered, I really should...", and "**I was supposed to read this book**", as in "What was my homework for today? Oh, right, I was supposed to..."

The form "ich solle" is subjunctive, which means you basically only need it to make reported speech sound formal:

> "Hast Du Peter nach den Deutsch-Hausaufgaben gefragt?" -- 
>   "Ja, er hat gesagt, ich **solle** das Buch lesen."

"Did you ask Peter about your German homework?" -- "Yes, he said I was supposed to read this book."

In everyday speech, however,

> "Hast Du Peter nach den Deutsch-Hausaufgaben gefragt?" -- 
>   "Ja, er hat gesagt, ich **soll** das Buch lesen."

is just fine.