# Übersetzung von "I am a PhD student in chemistry"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I am a PhD student in chemistry.

Wie übersetzt man das ins Deutsche?

> (a) Ich bin Doktorstudent in Chemie.
>
> (b) Ich bin PhD Student in Chemie.

In einer Antwort zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/es-soll-sollte-geben-as-in-there-should-be/) wurde erwähnt, dass das Wort *PhD* (noch?) nicht gängig in der deutschen Sprache ist. Ist es so, dass wenn man (b) sagt, fast niemand in Deutschland verstehen würde?

Und ist *in* die richtige Präposition?

Comment: An der Uni ist auch die Formulierung "ich promoviere in Chemie" üblich.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In der deutschen (Umgags-)Sprache ist man kein "Student" mehr, wenn man an seinem Doktor arbeitet. Deshalb:

> (c) Ich bin Doktorand in Chemie.  *oder*
>   
> (d) Ich mache gerade meinen Doktor in Chemie. *oder*
>   
>  (e) Ich arbeite an meinem Doktor in Chemie.

"PhD" wird eigentlich nur im universitären Umfeld verstanden, aber nicht benutzt - außer man macht seinen Doktor im englischsprachigen Raum, dann kann es sein, dass man auch den englischen Begriff nimmt.

Comment: Insbesondere ist etwas Vorsicht mit dem Begriff PhD angebracht. Nicht jeder Doktortitel darf als PhD bezeichnet werden. Darüber ist sogar mal ein Max-Planck Direktor gestolpert.

Comment: Dass Doktoranden keine Studenten mehr seien, glauben aber auch nur diese ;)

Comment: Kannst du noch etwas zur Präposition *in* sagen?

Comment: @Wolf: An was dachtest Du? Den unterschied dass man ohne Präpostion studiert, aber mit "in" promoviert?

Comment: Ich hatte probiert, eine Antwort zu formulieren, aber letztlich aufgegeben. *In* schien mir eine Art von Kurzschreibweise für *im Fach(bereich)* zu sein...

Comment: @RomanReiner: Das hängt vermutlich mit dem typischen Aufgabenfeld zusammen. Die Bezeichnung "Student" verbindet man eher mit jemandem, der Lehrveranstaltungen besucht, Übungsaufgaben bearbeitet, Prüfungen schreibt, allenfalls aus einem Nebenjob ein Einkommen hat etc. All das trifft auf Doktoranden im deutschsprachigen Raum oft nicht zu; in vielen Fällen gehen diese täglich als Universitätsmitarbeiter in ihr Büro, wo sie neben der Forschung diverse andere Verpflichtungen wie das *Betreuen* oder *Organisieren* von Lehrveranstaltungen wahrnehmen, und bekommen dafür ein festes Gehalt.