# Difference between “sollen” and “müssen”

Tags: difference, verb-choice, verb-usage

I can’t quite grasp the difference between *sollen* and *müssen.* They both express a duty, something that has to be done. In Italian, my native language, we just have one word for both, and so I can’t decide when I can only use one of them. In some uses, the two are equivalent, right? So, when is it right to use *müssen* and when *sollen?*

Could you explain the difference in connotation through examples?

Comment: Related: [Difference between “Das sollst du nicht” and “Das solltest …”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17300/difference-between-das-sollst-du-nicht-and-das-solltest)

Comment: As a very rough approximation, *sollen* is similar to *shall* while *müssen* is similar to *must* (unsurprisingly).

Comment: @reinierpost: Für die Verneinung (must not, should not) ist die Annäherung falsch.

Comment: 'Sollen' can often be translated as 'to be supposed to'. 'Soll ich das machen?' / ' Am I supposed to do this?'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to its definition, *sollen* is used if something is not completely obligatory, but it would be really disadvantageous for somebody if the opposite happened, whereas *müssen* is really strict and utilized to determine rules and laws or if something is an inevitable condition for something else. Note that the opposite of *müssen* (a prohibition) is *nicht dürfen,* whereas *nicht müssen* means *to not need to.* Here are a few examples for which only *müssen* is applicable.

> Sie müssen sich anmelden, bevor Sie die Forenbeiträge lesen können.
>   *You have to log in before you can see the forum posts.*
>
> Das Licht muss um 23 Uhr abgeschaltet werden.
>   *The lights have to be switched off at 11 PM.*
>
> Sie müssen mindestens 50 Punkte erreichen, um die Prüfung zu bestehen.
>   *You have to score at least 50 credits to pass the exam.*
>
> Sie **dürfen** diesen Bereich **nicht** betreten.
>   *You must not enter this area.*

Furthermore, *müssen* is used if somebody has to keep an appointment or perform an order they were given:

> Morgen muss ich zum Zahnarzt.
>   *I have to see a dentist tomorrow*
>
> Er musste sein Zimmer aufräumen.
>   *He had to tidy up his room.*

An exception would be the Ten Commandments which are determined using *sollen* (e.g. *Du sollst nicht stehlen*) in German despite they are probably meant to be completely obligatory. I don‘t exactly know why, but determining compulsory rules with *sollen* has become unusual and sounds outdated, at least in written language, so nobody would write house rules or an employment contract with *sollen.*

However, there are lots of situations where both words can be used as synonyms, i. e. in spoken German, because *sollen* is considered a little more polite and often preferred if you give somebody an order or hint. To make it even more friendly, the subjunctive form *sollte* is often used.

> Du solltest mehr schlafen, sonst kannst du dich nicht mehr konzentrieren.
>   *You should sleep more, otherwise you won't be able to concentrate anymore.*
>
> Du sollst doch nicht immer deine Hose schmutzig machen!
>   *Didn't I tell you to not dirty your trousers every time?* (Often, parents criticize their children like this)
>
> Der Staat sollte sich viel mehr um die Einwanderer kümmern.
>   *The government should care way more for the immigrants.*

You could use *müssen* resp. *nicht dürfen* in those three sentences as well, but it would sound way more harsh than *sollen* and indicate that the speaker is already really angry and/or uncomprehending about the way somebody else is behaving.

Comment: *It would be really disadvantageous for somebody if the opposite happened" ist keine notwendige Bedingung für *sollen*.

Answer (score 7):

*Müssen* expresses general obligation. *Sollen* is an obligation given by someone. So when you use *sollen*, you do imply that someone told you so.

> Ich muss gehen.
> I have to go (for whatever reason).
>
> Ich soll gehen.
> I have (just) been told to go.

Common contexts for *sollen* are doctors orders as well as the ten commandments.

Note that the the situation is different for *sollte* and *müsste*.

Comment: Concise and (I would assume) helpful. +1

Comment: How is the situation different for sollte and müsste?

Answer (score 3):

**Müssen** is quite more narrow in it's use:

> Ich muss noch aufräumen. (I have to tidy up.)

This is a duty/necessity given to me by someone else or myself. I *think* that I have to fulfill it.

> Ich muss den Kaffee ohne Milch trinken. (I have to drink coffee without milk.)

There is no milk left, so I have to drink coffee without milk. This is due to external circumstances.

> Das muss Fred sein. (This has to be Fred.)

As I was expecting Fred, I reason that it is him.

When using „müssen“ as perfect auxiliary, this use remains as only option:

> Die Strasse ist nass, es muss geregnet haben. (The street is wet, it must have rained.)

I reason that it must have rained as the street is wet.

**Sollen** is far wider. It is difficult to grasp, as there are many uses.

> Ich soll mein Zimmer aufräumen.

I have to tidy up my room, but it is not as strict as „müssen“.

> In Jerusalem soll sich mein Schicksal entscheiden. (My fate will be decided in Jerusalem.)

„Soll“ serves as a replacement for „werden“ (Futur) here. It can be used to talk about things that are supposed to happen in the future.

> Dein Wille soll geschehen!

Here, it serves as a replacement for optative mood, which is usually conveyed by Konjunktiv I.

> Er soll trinken. (He should drink or I've heard that he drinks.)

„Sollen“ is often used to voice out assumptions. This meaning is left when used as perfect auxiliary:

> Er soll getrunken haben (I've heard/I assume that he drank.)

I think that „sollen“ is the most difficult modal verb.

Answer (score 2):

Right. Romance or Latin languages do not distinguish between *sollen* und *müssen*. [Amazingly, automatic translators like Google-translate or Babelfish have big problems with it (presently).] The general rule is that:

- *Sollen* is subjective. Someone (possibly including myself) believes something should be done.

> Ich soll aufräumen. Er soll etwas mitbringen. Du sollst still sein. Wir sollen morgen wiederkommen.

- *Müssen* is (supposed to be) objective. The reason why something must be done cannot or does not need to be explained.

> Das muss gemacht werden. Da muss er durch. Da muss man mitmachen. Du musst es ihm sagen.

As you reference Italian (ciao!), I guess you would translate by *dovere*. You might think of *sollen* as the conditional (*dovresti*) and *müssen* as the direct correspondence (*devi ballare*). But both modal verbs exist in conditional form (*Konjunktiv*): *ich sollte gehen*, *ich müsste schlafen*. And there the easy rule goes …

Better think of

- *müssen* as an obligation (*dovere*) and
- ***sol**len* should remind you **s**ome**o**ne t**ol**d

to start with.

Comment: Dinge, die man tun muss, können auch erklärt werden während Dinge, die man tun soll, auch nicht immer erklärt werden. Das ist also kein geeignetes Distinktionsmerkmal. Auch schließt, dass es jemand gesagt hat, *müssen* nicht aus.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers: "sollen" whenever in laws always has the meaning of "müssen" - there are "Soll-Bestimmungen" (which are compulsory) which are opposed to "Kann-Bestimmungen" (which are optional).

I suppose this is derived from some older use of the word, as is also reflected in the ten commandments (as mentioned elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to consider müssen/must like something that must be done no matter what. It's a rule. You must wash your hands, otherwise you can't touch the food.

Sollen/shall is what your doctor will tell you: you shall stop smoking if you want to live. You shall undergo surgery. It's a prescription. It isn't something that must be done, it's something that it's up to you but it's simply the only way. That's why, I think, it's called "moral obligation".

Edit: well, hope this helps.

Comment: Italian is not one of the languages allowed to communicate here. Please use only German or English.

Comment: You can touch food with dirty hands. It is absolutely possible. It's disgusting, but definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a key source of misunderstanding for English speakers is translating müssen into must. Better translations of this verb are "to have to" or "to need to"

Eg Ich muss = I have to, I need to
Ich muss nicht = I don't have to, I don't need to (*not* "I must not")

Answer (score -2):

Müssen is an obligation.

Sollen express something you have to do but it is an order or a suggestion from someone else!

Comment: Even though getting new people to the site is always welcome, I have to point out that this answer does not add anything new that has not yet been said. This needs to be fleshed out quite a bit.

Comment: @Chieron: Wenn man nichts neues zu sagen hat soll man es lassen, nicht ausschmücken.