# why have they used "müssen" instead of "sollen" here?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verb

I've read through this post on the differences between müssen and sollen:
[Difference between “sollen” and “müssen”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18147/difference-between-sollen-and-m%C3%BCssen)

I was trying to decide how to say "you should have told him" (e.g. that jumping off a cliff was dangerous) but I'm confused about the difference between the following two sentences.

I had thought the translation would be:

> Das hättest du ihm sagen sollen.

however the answer (in the exercise book) was:

> Das hättest du ihm sagen müssen.

What is the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: Whose answer do you mean?

Comment: None of your examples is wrong for the translation. But I think it is a duplicate and well explained in the thread you reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Sollen*, in your sentence 1, is more a recommendation; meaning it would have been your duty to tell him so.

*Müssen*, in sentence 2, would express absolute necessity. And in the given situation I would always use *müssen*. It is much stronger.