# “sollten” in the context of newspaper headlines

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Typically in basic German grammar lessons, they explain the word *sollten* as something like *should* as in:

> Ich sollte nach Hause gehen. → I should go home.

However, when I look at some newspaper headlines, I see stuff like:

> Hacker im Auftrag Russlands sollten Trump zum Sieg verhelfen.

A translation like the following doesn’t make sense:

> Russian hackers should help Trump to victory.

How should I interpret *sollten* here?

Comment: _sollen_ can also mean _being supposed to_. In this case a phrase like "Hackers were meant to help Trump" makes perfect sense.

Comment: Is this like a past tense of sollen? So sollten has two meanings where one is the past tense of sollten and the other is "should"?

Comment: In the case of *Hacker ... sollten ...* yes. They were *told* to help Trump win. It is not the Konjunktiv here in the sense of a recommendation like *Menschen sollten lieber...*.

Comment: @Ingmar, please turn your comment into an answer, as quite obviosuly there is noone else addressing the OP's question and answer it correctly.

Comment: I think Thorsten's answer pretty much nails it.

Comment: @henry you could see the english "should" as a past tense of "shall", though it is usually not used like that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Sollen* also has the meaning *to be supposed to*, *to be meant to* or *to be told to*. It can also be used in combination with *angeblich*. Then (but also without the *angeblich*) it means something like *to be said to* or *to supposedly have done something*.

Examples:

> Mama sagt, ich soll einkaufen gehen.
>   Mum told me to go grocery shopping.
>
> Die drei Männer sollen zunächst die Bank ausgeraubt haben.
>   The three men are said to have robbed the bank first.
>
> Im Winter soll es oft kalt sein.
>   It is said that it is often cold in winter.

Please note that the real meaning is often hard to find out without further context:

> Ich sollte einkaufen gehen.

This can either mean

> I was supposed to go grocery shopping (but didn't, because ...)

or

> I really should go grocery shopping (because there's no food in the house).

In your example, the *sollten* states the fact that it is proven that hackers were instructed to help Trump win. This is not to be confused with the Konjunktiv *sollten etwas tun*, which would express a recommendation.

Comment: "proven" ... well... in the context of a newspaper headline this is a bit of a strong word...

Comment: Depends on how much you trust the paper... If a paper titles that way, it states a fact, a fact must be verifyable (unless you are from the post-factual community) and thus provable. So yes, making a matter-of-fact statement you better have proof.

Answer (score 6):

Other answeres have pointed out the different possible meanings of sollen. But I would like to draw your attention to the fact that the past tense sollten, not sollen is used.

## Should, be supposed to

> Hacker im Auftrag Russlands **sollten** Trump zum Sieg **verhelfen**.

Probably really means that the Hackers were supposed to help Trump/ were instructed to help Trump. So here, I guess, "sollten" really has the meaning should. This connects with "im Auftrag Russlands", so it means that they were supposed to help Trump, because Russia ordered it.

## allegedly

> Hacker im Auftrag Russlands **sollen** Trump zum Sieg **verholfen haben**.

If you change the time of the sentence, now the meaning of "sollen" is "allegedly". "Hacker ordered by Russia allegedly helped Trump to victory"

If "sollen" means "allegedly", it is mostly used as "sollen", not "sollten", because it is still not proven in the present.

Answer (score 5):

You can't go far wrong, by translating this as "`supposedly`" (do **NOT** use "were supposed to", which can be interpreted as "ought to have" ("Russian hackers ought to have helped Trump"??)).

More natural to native English ears is "`allegedly`".

"Sollen" is used by the media for the same reason as "allegedly", "reportedly", "soucres say" and the like ... to avoid libel suits.

Comment: +1 for the fitting explanation in this context, while leaving the other meanings of "sollen" (which the OP obviously already knows about) out.

Comment: No, in this context *sollten* actually means *were instructed to*. Otherwise it would have been phrased *sollen ... verholfen haben*.

Comment: A very good point (=1). However, generally, I would say that `sollen` can be replaced by `allegedly` in headlines. Would you agree?

Comment: An example for *allegedly* would read like *Die Männer sollen zunächst ... haben*.

Answer (score 3):

The German verb *sollen* correpsonds to the English verb *shall*, but their uses are different. By itself it has the meaning of [expressing an instruction, command, or obligation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shall). Examples given in answers to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18147/difference-between-sollen-and-m%c3%bcssen) may be helpful.

The *sollte* that you have encountered so far was [Konjunktiv II](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:sollen) and indeed matches *should* well. The *sollte* in the headline is just past tense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mothertongue German Guy.

"sollten" is a word which can be used in many cases:

- "Russian hackers should help Trump to victory"
- "Russian hackers are supposed to help Trump to victory"

are both *"Hacker im Auftrag Russlands sollten Trump zum Sieg verhelfen"*.

You can also say *"Sollten Sie Probleme haben, kontaktieren sie den Support"*, also *"If you have problems, contact our support"*.

German is a difficult language. I know!

Comment: "German is a difficult language. I know!" - no, you don't - coz you ar a German Guy ;-)

Comment: Oh, believe me as a German: sometimes if you read what other German people write (and how they write it) you *can tell* that German is hard even for Germans...

Comment: Although the same thing can be said for writers of just about any language …